# How does a bean name relate to a component?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following in my application-context.xml file:

```
<bean id="reportingDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.1:5432/reports"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="reportingSql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="DataSource" ref="reportingDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and my route (snippet) looks like this:

```
.to("reportingSql:insert into my_table (uuid, name, created_at, created_by) values ('a','namename', 1, 2)")
```

clearly I am just sticking my toe in the waters here.

This code generates an error in `/var/log/tomcat/whistler.log`:

```
 ...due to: No component found with scheme: reportingSql
```

If I change 'reportingSql' in the xml file and in the route to be just 'sql', I get further - the error is gone. Is 'sql' magic, somehow?

And if it is, I suppose that's ok, but what if I wanted to use an additional data source? I could not refer to them both as 'sql'.

Answer (score 1):

A component is resolved through a `ComponentResolver`. By default, the `DefaultComponentResolver` use these strategies:

1. Look for the component in the camel registry. If an instance is found, a conversion to `Component` is made
2. Use a default `FactoryFinder` to instantiate a new component. This factory use registered classes in properties under `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/`

On other words, what you want to do is possible: Camel should check a named instance in the registry. However, in your example, you are using a spring file to register beans, and java to create a route.

With Spring, when you use `<camelContext../>`, a `SpringCamelContext` is created, instead of the `DefaultCamelContext`. This context use severals services allowing to integrate better in a Spring application. One of this service is the `ApplicationContextRegistry` which integrate Spring beans into the camel registry. It's this registry which allows using bean registered in Spring as `Component`.

So, check if you are using a `CamelContext` from a Spring context. If not, or you can't use a managed camelContext, you can try to use the `SpringCamelContext` or an `ApplicationContextRegistry`.

See:

- [DefaultComponentResolver](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponentResolver.java)
- [ApplicationContextRegistry](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/spi/ApplicationContextRegistry.java)